# Gesture Builder in API 27

Tags: android, api, android-studio, sdk, gesture

I try to learn Gesture Handling in Android and I tried this tutorial: www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_Android_Custom_Gesture_Recognition_with_Android_Studio

My problem is, that I can not download Samples for SDK in my Android Studio 3.0.1 because there is just no option called like that: 
[image: sdk manager]
So I tried this App on Appstore: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pack.GestureApp
But when I try to read the file like this:

```
        gLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gesture);
```

the gLibrary is always empty.
So I tried to find the official Gesture Builder Application here: https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html and in Android Studio: File/New/Import Sample:
[image: android samples]
as u can see, nothing there too.

I also tried to get a old (API 17) version running: https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples
but I just got errors over and over again.

**So lets get to my question. How to build a gesture file today with API 26/27 or how to get the old Gesture Builder (running).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by downloading all API 27 package

[image: I solve this problem by downloading all API 27 package]