# Gesture Builder in 2018?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create a simple gesture-based app with custom gestures. However, I can't seem to get the Gesture Builder sample/app onto my emulator. I have tried to download the full API 27 per the advice of:

[Gesture Builder in API 27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358964/gesture-builder-in-api-27)

However, that didn't work for me. I did try to download the Gesture Builder from the Play Store on a Nexus 5 emulator, but the gesture file won't save to the emulator's virtual sd card.

Can someone steer me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with following steps:

- Download gesture Builder from google play.
- Make gestures. If you save Gesture it will show you directory to
  gesture.txt

> (on my device:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/pack.GestureApp/files/gesture.txt)

- then connect your phone to pc with USB debugging and locate SDK
  platform-tools folder in cmd

> (my location:    D:\Dokumenty\SDK\platform-tools)

- then write: `adb -d pull directory_to_gesture.txt` .

**my command:**

> ```
> > adb    -d pull
> > /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/pack.GestureApp/files/gesture.txt
> ```

**And it copy gestures to android studio**.

verify by: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/pack.GestureApp/files/gesture.txt: 1 file pulled.